# StringFormat in XAML, WPF : Currency Formatting

Tags: wpf, currency, string-formatting

How can i obtain currency formatting according to my country i.e indian rupee, INR or Rs ??

Please tell me the way to achieve this ?? 
Right now when i use **StringFormat="{}{0:C}"**, "$" is being used

I have gone through this [link](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/18/getting-a-wpf-application-to-pick-up-the-correct-regional.aspx) and i am able to achieve the desired result but i am worried about using this in my project. **Is this code safe ??**

What does this line mean in the above link **"when you test functionality related to settings change it’s important you start the program directly from a folder window, if you run it from within Visual Studio or any other program you may get incorrect results."**

Comment: The code you linked is perfectly safe, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I never had any incorrect results with using the coded you liked.

Comment: Actually i have written a hell lot of code and only part left is StringFormat.
The reason i am getting worried is that on that link it says "You need to update all bindings again and there are some other warnings too"
I have so many bindings so i can't afford to re-write again. 
Are you people sure that nothing else is needed to be done if i use that code ??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify the culture in your binding like this:

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=nl-BE}"
```

nl-BE is belgian culture, you can exchange it with Indian culture info, I don't know that ;-)

Comment: dats a good solution. Will choose between this or the solution mentioned in Question above.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can set your current thread to the right culture, so you will use it everywhere in your application:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
```