# How to format a textbox to currency

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Is there a way to format a textbox input. I want it to show the $ in the textbox and then input from right to left wit two decimals.

Comment: Have a look at this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734831/stringformat-in-xaml-wpf-currency-formatting

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ...?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2006/03/21/556434.aspx

Comment: That was exactly the problem I was having with it. Do you know what the code for this is in VB

Comment: Try running the code from the blog entry through a C# to VB translator, like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox.aspx) and set its [`Mask` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) like `$999,999.00`.

Comment: Does that accept input from right to left?  Does it work the same way in WPF?

Comment: is there a way to not show the underscores values

Comment: @BURTONJOHN: You still haven't told us whether this is Winforms or WPF.

Comment: Windows Form Application